# AngularJS: can't access object property from factory

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a beginner issue with my AngularJS very simple code: I'm trying to pass data from a factory to a controller and print the object returned to my view, here's my code:

```
angular.module('app').factory('blogFactory',function(){
   return {
        //EDIT
        post:{"author":"Bob","name":"smith","content":"some content"},
        read: function(){
            return this.post; 
        }
   }
});
```

In the controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller('MainCtrl',['$scope','blogFactory'], function($scope, blogFactory){
   $scope.datas = blogFactory.read();
   console.log($scope.datas);});
```

When I `console.log($scope.datas` it logs the object fine. In the view I 'm unable to access the object's properties:

```
<section class="overview">
     <article ng-repeat="data in datas">
         <p>{{data.name}}</p> //Doesn't display anything
         <p>{{data}}</p>     // Displays the object
     </article>
 </section>
```

Does anyone has any idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: is $scope.datas an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any property called `name` in  `$scope.datas`

```
{"author":"Bob","content":"some content"}
```

You must be printing `datas.author`.

That's why          `<p>{{data.name}}</p>` doesn't display any data.

As per your factory code, `post` is an object. But in your view you are using

```
 <article ng-repeat="data in datas">
```

Which is not required. Just `datas` is enough to get that individual post

Comment: Thanks @mohamedrias this solves it. I've been using a `ng-repeat` directive beforehand and that was the problem. @mohamedrias @user: sorry for wasting you time and thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine I have tested it:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[])
app.factory('blogFactory',function(){
return {
    post:{"author":"Bob","content":"some content"},
    read: function(){
        return this.post; 
    }
}
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,blogFactory){
  alert();
$scope.datas = blogFactory.read();
console.log($scope.datas);
})
```

For the view:

```
<body ng-controller ="MainCtrl">
<section class="overview">
 <article ng-repeat="data in datas" >
     <p>{{data.name}}</p> 
     <p>{{data}}</p>    
 </article>
</section>
</body>
```

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer, do you think there could be a bug with my install? It's weird. I'll try to launch it in another project and let you know

Comment: @t3__rry see this app.controller('MainCtrl',['$scope','blogFactory'], function($scope,blogFactory){,  if I'm using in this way It doesn't provide any output.